# Kivy_Text_INPUT_Multiline_app (frames)

Tags: kivy

I am developing some app in kivy,I need to display mulitple line of string in a text input.How to do it?

If any examples please do post it.

Answer (score 0):

An example is right [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html) together with description. You didn't provide any code or basically anything I could use, so I'll do it this way:

```
<Box>:
    TextInput:
        id: mytextinput
        multiline: True ## defaults to True, but so you could see how it works
        text: 'something'
    Button:
        on_release: root.update_text('new value')
```

this will be your kv file/string for a TextInput no matter where you'll put it and `id` is identificator of how to access that widget, then in python

```
class Box(BoxLayout):
    def update_text(self, value):
        self.ids.mytextinput.text = value
```

It means that whatever widget you have and TextInput is its child in kv file/string, you will access it through `ids` dictionary and change its variable `text` to your desired value with calling custom `update_text(<string>)` in your class.